# Highlight Search term in returned Result in ASP.NET MVC Using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to highlight the search term in returned search results? 
I searched a lot and read lots of articles but all of them are very much different from my structure

Here is my controller

```
public ActionResult Help(string searchString)
{
    var repsearch = new RepositorySearch();
    List<Question> question = new List<Question>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        question = repsearch.GetAllQuestion().Where(n => n.Qu.Contains(searchString)).ToList();
    }
    return Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? (ActionResult)PartialView("_QuestionPartial", question) : View(question);
}
```

and here is my ajax

```
$('#FormSearch').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var url = '/Home/Help?' + searchString;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: { searchString: $('#search').val(); },
        success: function (result) {
            window.history.replaceState("#intagsname", "Title", url);
            $('#intagsname').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is _QuestionPartial

```
@using iranhoidaytour_com.Models
@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (Question q in Model)
        {
            <li>
                <h5>@q.Qu</h5>
                <p>@q.Ans</p>
            </li>
         }
     </ul>
 }
```

How do I highlight the search term in returned search results?

Here is my html for the main view

```
<div class="row" id="searchhelp">
    <div class="container">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Help", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { @id = "FormSearch", @class = "form-group container" }))
        {
            @Html.TextBox("search", null, new { @class = "form-control col-md-10", @placeholder = "What Is Your Question?Enter Keyword!" })
            <button type="submit" class="left " id="btn-search">
                <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
        }
    </div>
</div>

<div id="helpicons" class="container">
    <div id="tagsname">
        <div id="intagsname">
            @Html.Partial("_QuestionPartial", Model)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not related, but just use `data: { searchString: $('#search').val(); },` (and delete everything between `event.preventDefault();` and `$.ajax({` and then in the controller delete `searchString = Request["search"];` (the parameter in your method will be correctly bound)

Comment: How do you want to 'highlight' the items?

Comment: I don' have any idea  how to highlight but just adding a class which it makes the term bolder or change the color it would be enough, thanks for your help you meant I should edit my entire code ? @StephenMuecke

Comment: No, but you do need to show the code for your `_QuestionPartial.cshtml` partial view (you can do this easily using some javascript)

Comment: you mean I can find easy way also to change the `CSS` of the searched term after implement this with java-script? @StephenMuecke

Comment: Yes, but show your code for the partial view (and also edit the code in your man view to show the element with `id="intagsname"`)

Comment: a little confused, but I work on it. and please if its possible for you and you find time, Appreciate if you help me more by answering this question and apply the edits. I'm really sorry and I know its a big request @StephenMuecke

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141635/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-neda-derakhshesh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use javascript to wrap any instances of the search text in an element with a class name

```
var container = $('#intagsname');
$('#FormSearch').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var searchString = $('#search').val(); // get the search string
    var replacement = '<span class="highlight">' + searchString + '</span>'; // define replacement text
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Help", "Home")', // don't hard code you url's
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: { searchString: searchString },
        success: function (result) {
            window.history.replaceState("#intagsname", "Title", url);
            $('#intagsname').html(result);
            var questions = container.find('h5'); // get all question text
            $.each(questions, function() {
                var text = $(this).html(); // get the text
                text = text.replace(new RegExp(searchString, 'g'), replacement); // replace it
                $(this).html(text); // update it
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Then create a style to highlight the search text, for example

```
.highlight {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

Alternatively, your could use a regex to modify the text to include the html tags in the controller, and then use `@Html.Raw()` in the view to display it.

Comment: Excuse me again, Dose it need `$.each(questions, function() {
                var text = $(this).html(); 
                text = text.replace(new RegExp(searchString, 'g'), replacement);
                $(this).html(text); 
            }` a close Parenthesis? when I put close Parenthesis it doesn't work at all but without Parenthesis works fine but no highlight yet

Comment: Excuse me, do you mind if I ask a new question about this code? I have some problem to understanding $.each and why replacement dosent happen

Comment: What problem are you having? I tested the code and it works fine.

Comment: yea it works fine, but replacement is not working`$.each(questions, function() {...` doesn't need close parenthesis? and with `)` at the end it stops working completely, it seems $.each loop is not running either. and also where should I put  `@Html.Raw()` exactly?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the closing `);` for the `$.each()` block. I will create a fiddle for you later today to show you how it works. The `.@Html.Raw()` is only applicable if you do the replacement in the controller method so that you passing html to the view (in which case it would be `<h5>@Html.Raw(q.Qu)</h5>`

Comment: Refer [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w50q65Lg/) - enter `car` in the textbox and click search (note I also had a typo in the class name)

Comment: really thank your time and fiddle, yea fiddle works completely fine also in my project. but while I use it in the ajax the problems comes with this error in console`http://localhost:60542/Home/@Url.Action(%22Help%22,%20%22Home%22)` `[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 7ms]` I think it needs some changes in route config

Comment: That suggests your script is in an external file (razor code is not parsed in external files). I would recommend you add `var url = '@Url.Action("Help", "Home")';` in your main view, and in the script, use `url: url,`